# Pick value from row when there is overlapping value in another column postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry, I am new to SQL so this might be a super dumb question
I currently have a table like:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| a | 12345 |
| b | 12345 |
| a | 12346 |
| a | 12347 |
| a | 12348 |

Is there some simplifying function in sql to always choose b as the value when the y value is the same?
Such that it looks something like:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| b | 12345 |
| a | 12346 |
| a | 12347 |
| a | 12348 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (y) t.*
from t
order by y, (x = 'b') desc;
```

This chooses one row per `value` with a preference for `'b'` over other values.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. I'm still new to SQL so do I replace value with y in this case? Also, if t is the table, what is t.*? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @LouisYe . . . I updated to use the correct column name.